# Change color of FEVD plot

Tags: python, plot, colors

I am creating a FEVD plot of a data set with several different variables. Due to the amount of variables, it is hard to spot the different colors in the plot as it is in only grey tones.

Here is a snippet

[image]

Is it possible to make the plot more colorful?

My code is as follows:

```
model = VAR(mdata)
results = model.fit(maxlags=2, ic='aic')
fevd = results.fevd(5)
results.fevd(20).plot(figsize=(20,20))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question!
I was just going to ask the same thing!